# How to correctly update a custom Angular 6 library, to Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to upgrade a custom library to angular 9 from 6.1 but I have no experience with that, so I wanted to know if the process is the same as updating an Angular Project from 6 to 9?

for that I would just follow this: https://update.angular.io/

My main doubt is, I have globally installed already Angular 9+ as I'm working on other projects that use it, so I'm not sure I need to do the "`ng update`" commands, but instead, should I just manually increment the version of my library `peerDependencies` and run a npm install?

The important file I think of this library is the package.json and this is its content:

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "xxxx"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

So my idea here is just to change these numbers to the correct ones for angular 9, and then run NPM install, then run the App locally and debug it until it works correctly and finally publish the npm package.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No. Don't  go for manual upgrade of cli version but need to upgrade it properly because angular 6.1 and 9+ is having major breaking changes so only follow the proper guidelines provided by angular team on https://update.angular.io/  .Because this is only the proper way to save  and reuse your app.